# How can add Amazon Wish List to my site? (PHP, jquery, CSS)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I want to add an `Amazon Books Wish List` to my site and I want to `style it with CSS`.

So, how can I do it? Should I use PHP or can I use Jquery?

Do you know PHP tutorials for it or any Jquery plug in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this before, but I believe you would need to sign up for an Amazon developer API key, then use the [Product Advertising API](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=5) to access wish lists information in XML. You can then parse the XML using PHP (or jQuery) then display the information however you list.

Here's a tutorial from Amazon as well: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=379